# How do I fix this problem in my music game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to work on a larger scale project (in terms of my current level) which is a music game. Everything is working fine in this code but occassionally, when I try to 'print (A)', (which can be seen on the last line of the code), it doesn't show the first letter of the song but sometimes it does. I'm not sure why this is.

here is the code:

```
import songsandartists
import random
import sys
import time

Authorised_players = ("jimmy", "tim", "amy", "bob")
Username = input("Please enter your username: ")
if Username.lower() in Authorised_players:
    print("Getting your game ready...")
else:
    print("Sorry you are not an authorised player")
    sys.exit("""
    You are no authorised to play, 
    Try contacting developers to authorise you :)
    EXITING GAME... """)

time.sleep(2)

Random_song = random.choice(songsandartists.Songs)
links = {
    "BOP": "DABABY",
    "NOBODY'S AROUND": "YNW MELLY",
    "LOADING": "CENTRAL CEE",
    "LAUGH NOW, CRY LATER": "DRAKE",
}
Reference = {
    "DABABY": "BOP",
    "YNW MELLY": "NOBODY'S AROUND",
    "CENTRAL CEE": "LOADING",
    "DRAKE": "LAUGH NOW, CRY LATER",
}
if Random_song in links:
    K = links.get(Random_song)
    A = Reference.get(K)[0]
    print(K)
    print(A)

Answer = input("What song do think do you think this artist made that start with the letter above? : ")

points = 0

if Answer.upper() == Random_song in links:
    points += 1
    print("Correct Answer")
    print("You have ", points, " points")
else:
    time.sleep(2)
    K = links.get(Random_song)
    F = Reference.get(K)[0:2]
    print(F)
    sec_attempt = input("You have one more chance, THINK!  : ")
    if sec_attempt.upper() == Random_song in links:
        print("Well done, You got it this time")
        points += 0.5
        print("You have ", points, " points")
    else:
        print("Incorrect, still wrong")
```

Answer (score 2):

Within a few minutes, I have realised my dumb mistake. In my imported 'Songs and Artists' file, all the songs and artists names were all lowercase and I've written them as uppercase in my Music game's dictionaries causing them not to work as they couldn't be found in the dictionaries. So basically, when I tried to search and get 'stuff' from the dictionary it wasn't able to therefore disabling me from printing anything from the dictionary.

What a noob mistake...smh.

Comment: Not a noob. A self-learner! It shows that you aren't just waiting for an answer in OS. GG!